# maya python + Pass variable on button press

Tags: python, maya

I have a script i wrote in python for maya and there are 3 buttons labeled X Y Z. Depending on which button is pressed I want a variable to pass a specific value to the function. How can I do this?? I've written in the comments for the button in regards to what I'm trying to pass. It seems to just print 'false' im not sure why.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class createMyLayoutCls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def show(self):
        self.createMyLayout()

    def createMyLayout(self):

        #check to see if our window exists
        if cmds.window('utility', exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI('utility')

        # create our window
        self.window = cmds.window('utility', widthHeight = (200, 200), title = 'Distribute', resizeToFitChildren=1, sizeable = False)

        cmds.setParent(menu=True)

        # create a main layout
        mainLayout = cmds.gridLayout( numberOfColumns=3, cellWidthHeight=(70, 50) )

        # X Y Z BUTTONS
        btnAlignX = cmds.button(label = 'X', width = 40, height = 40, c = self.TakeAction) # should pass 'axis='X"
        btnAlignY = cmds.button(label = 'Y', width = 40, height = 40, c = self.TakeAction) # should pass 'axis='Y"
        btnAlignZ = cmds.button(label = 'Z', width = 40, height = 40, c = self.TakeAction) # should pass 'axis='Z"

        # show window
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def TakeAction(self, axis=''):
        print axis

        if axis == 'x':
            print 'you selected x'
        if axis == 'y':
            print 'you selected y'
        if axis == 'y':
            print 'you selected z'   

b_cls = createMyLayoutCls()  
b_cls.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `lambda` to give each button command its own mini-function:

```
btnAlignX = cmds.button(label='X', c=lambda *_:self.TakeAction('X'))
btnAlignY = cmds.button(label='Y', c=lambda *_:self.TakeAction('Y'))
btnAlignZ = cmds.button(label='Z', c=lambda *_:self.TakeAction('Z'))
```

Comment: I changed it to this and it errors saying # Error: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given) # .....

btnAlignX = cmds.button(label='X', c=lambda:self.TakeAction(axis='x'))

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot Maya adds an argument. Added `*_` to accept and ignore any arguments passed to the lambda function

Answer (score 3):

To substitute lambda, you can use partial :

```
from functools import partial

btnAlignX = cmds.button(label='X', c=partial(self.TakeAction, 'X'))
```

Both lambda and partial should work.

Hope it helps.